# NGINX ingress controller timing out request after 60s

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

When a request takes over 60s to respond it seems that the ingress controller will bounce

From what I can see our NGINX ingress controller returns 504 to the client after a request takes more than 60s to process.  I can see this from the NGINX logs:

```
2019/01/25 09:54:15 [error] 2878#2878: *4031130 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.244.0.1, server: myapplication.com, request: "POST /api/text HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.244.0.39:45606/api/text", host: "myapplication.com"
10.244.0.1 - [10.244.0.1] - - [25/Jan/2019:09:54:15 +0000] "POST /api/text HTTP/1.1" 504 167 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.1.6" 2940 60.002 [default-myapplication-service-80] 10.244.0.39:45606 0 60.000 504 bdc1e0571e34bf1223e6ed4f7c60e19d
```

The second log item shows 60 seconds for both **upstream response time** and **request time** (see [NGINX log format here](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/log-format.md))

But I have specified all the timeout values to be 3 minutes in the ingress configuration:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: aks-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/send_timeout: "3m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "3m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "3m"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "3m"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myapplication.com
    secretName: tls-secret
  rules:
  - host: myapplication.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: myapplication-service
          servicePort: 80
```

What am I missing?

I am using nginx-ingress-1.1.0 and k8s 1.9.11 on Azure (AKS).

Comment: Can you grab the actual nginx.conf from one of the controller Pods and post it? `kubectl exec $pod cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf` should do it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue was fixed by provided integer values (in seconds) for these annotations:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "180"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
```

It seems that [this variation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx) of the NGINX ingress controller requires such.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting your solution. Worked like a charm for me, too

Comment: Does this mean that it's not possible to set it in milliseconds?

Answer (score 1):

Because you appear to be using the actual ingress from ngnix.com, you need to use `nginx.org/proxy-connect-timeout: "3m"` style annotations, as one can see in 
 [their example](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/v1.1.0/examples/customization/cafe-ingress-with-annotations.yaml#L6-L7)

I am still pretty sure that my debugging trick of `kubectl cp`-ing the `nginx.conf` off the controller Pod would have helped you debug that situation on your own, but for sure reading the documentation for your ingress controller will go a long way, too

While this might not matter to you, their [latest release](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/releases) is also 1.4.3 so I hope you are on an old version on purpose.

Comment: So it seems you are referring to this NGINX' ingress controller (https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress)  and not the one built and maintained by the Kubernetes community (https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx)

Comment: It was a reasonable guess, given that you said version 1.1.0 and there is [no such kubernetes-ingress version](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/releases) (nor [any such image](https://quay.io/repository/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller?tab=tags)) but whaddayaknow, [v1.1.0 of nginxinc](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/releases/tag/v1.1.0)

Comment: Ah, I mistook the chart version. Apologies. This stuff is all a bit fresh still.